# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-x^{1/n})^p$ converges for all $0<x \leq 1$ and $p>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let's consider the following series:

$$f(x,p)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-x^{1/n})^p$$

Since we have for $x>0$:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{1/n}=1$$

Now I have a hunch (supported by numerics) that $f(x,p)$ converges under the following conditions only:

$$0<x \leq 1, ~~~~p>1$$

Of course, it could potentially converge for $x>1$ as well, but I'm not interested in this case.

So how do I prove this?

Wolfram Alpha says 'comparison test', but I don't know which series to compare it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$1-x^{1/n}=1-\exp\left(\frac{\ln x}{n}\right)=-\frac{\ln x}{n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
so we see that the given series has the same nature of the Riemann series
$$\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$$
which is convergent for $p>1$.

Answer (score 2):

$\big( 1-x^{1/n} \big)^p= \big(1-\exp \frac{\ln x}{n}\big)^p
\sim \left( -\frac{\ln x}{n}\right)^p$, as $n$ tends to $0$. And $\sum_{n \geq 1} n^{-p}$ converges when $p>1$...